# Unable to receive data sent using NSStream objects

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstream

In my app I doing something very similar to what is done in the [WiTap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html) project. I use Bonjour to discover peers and then send data over the socket to perform an initial handshake.

I'm able to see the data being sent OTA using Cocoa Packet Analyzer. But the `stream: handleEvent:` function is never called on the receiving peer side.

What I am able to see is:

- Sometimes, when the peer that sent the data exits, the receiver peer seems to get the data.
- Sometimes I am able to see an `NSStreamEventErrorOccurred` error in the handler function.

I'm unable to see any noticeable pattern on when the above behavior occurs.

Here is a bit of the code that might be helpful.

PacketSender and PacketReceiver objects are singletons. 
I have verified multiple times that the correct (and the only) instance of these objects are set as delegates while debugging:

```
if (![netService getInputStream:&_inStream outputStream:&_outStream]) 
    {
        [Utilities showAlert:@"Failed connecting to server"];
        return BM_ERROR_NETSERVICE_STREAM_FAIL;
    }

    if(!sharedProtocolManager.mPacketSender)
    {
        sharedProtocolManager.mPacketSender = [PacketSender sharedSender];
    }

    if(!sharedProtocolManager.mPacketReceiver)
    {
        sharedProtocolManager.mPacketReceiver = [PacketReceiver sharedReceiver];
    }

    if(!sharedProtocolManager.mPacketSender || !sharedProtocolManager.mPacketReceiver)
    {
        return BM_ERROR_FAIL;
    }

    [PacketReceiver setupInStream:_inStream];
    [PacketSender setupOutStream:_outStream];
}
```

Inside the PacketReceiver setupInStream: function I have:

```
if (sharedPacketReceiver->mInStream != inStream)
    {
        [sharedPacketReceiver->mInStream release];
        sharedPacketReceiver->mInStream = [inStream retain];
    }

    sharedPacketReceiver->mInStream.delegate = sharedPacketReceiver;
```

Any answers or even suggestions on ways to debug this further would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the NSStream delegate properly? If yes, post your code

Comment: The delegate  is able to receive the NSStreamEventOpenCompleted event, so I doubt that could be the issue. Besides I am able to receive the NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable, albeit intermittently and rarely. It's a little bit difficult to post the code because of the the multiple objects involved, I will try and add it to the post anyhow.